# Suggestions for git workflow for multiple projects and non-developers

Tags: git, workflow

I have what I think is an interesting use case that I think git could help with, but I am at a loss for how to organize such a repository. We have a small team (4-6 programmers) who are responsible for writing scripts and small programs that move from Developing > Staging > Production phases. No one on our team has any experience with a VCS/DVCS and right now, version control is managed by file name conventions on their local machines, and the production code sits on a central server.

In the next 6 months, we will be moving from local development environments (each programmer has a number of development tools running on their local machine) to a central server model. This central server model will also require our programmers to have their files hosted on server, instead of locally. We would like to move toward (any kind of) VCS at the same time as this migration.

So some specifics:

- Production code can either be project-specific or more general, and used by multiple programmers
- Project-based code can either be a single file or small number of files (so from this perspective, having individual git repos sees inefficient)
  *It's very unlikely that two programmers would need to work on the same file at the same time
- Our workflow should incorporate Development, Staging and Production code
- Our programmers may occasionally need access to Development code, such as when someone goes on vacation (but I suppose this can be worked around)

I don't have any experience with git other than very simple local repos for my own projects. From what I've been reading, git is light-weight and flexible enough to accommodate a wide range of configurations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can keep two repos. One repo can be used as `Production` version, while the other one will have `Staged` code. Configure `Production` repo's origin to the location of `Staged` repo and so you will be able to move `Staged` code to `Production` by using `git pull origin`. Further you can use non-master `git` branches in the `Staged` repo as the `Development` code .

Comment: Thanks @ZeekHuge. Would it make sense to have these as monolith repos (all project and general code in one large repo) ? Would each programmer need their own private repo hosted on the server?

Comment: What do you mean by "general code" ?

Comment: @ZeekHuge general code would be code that is not project-specific (helper functions, etc)

Comment: That would mostly be a matter of personal preference. I would have maintained a different repository, which is still shared between developers so that the tools could be used by others too. `Production` and `Staged` repo should only contain the bussiness-logic code. Nothing else.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. If you'd like to put your comments into an answer, I'd be happy to accept the answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks :) I think I should delete the comments ?

Comment: I don't think they need to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and secure solution would be to use 3 different git repos.

- Repo 1 : `Production`
- Repo 2 : `Staged`
- Repo 3 : `Tools`

**Production repo**: The `Production` repo should be used as the main code repository and only the maintainer should be allowed to have access to it. This repo should be configured something like this :

```
git config --local remote.staged <path/to/staged/repo>
```

This configuration will allow the production-maintainer to do a simple `git pull staged master` to get code from `Staged` repository to `Production` repository.

**Staged repo**: The `master` branch of the `Staged` repository can be used as "Staged code" and other branches as "Development code".

**Tools repo**: Further, the `Tools` repo should be used as a repository for general tools that the developers use. Ideally, each tool inside the `Tools` repo should be a git-repo submodule in itself, but that will make the repo a bit complicated I guess.

**Note** that these repos (mainly the `Staged` and the `Production`) essentially contain your bussiness, hence they should be very clean and handy. So, keep the minimum required yet sufficient only code in the `Production` repo. And try same (with probably a bit less intensity) for the `Staged` repo.